# Flutter - Clickable OnTap from List

Tags: list, flutter, screen

I'm learning flutter and hit a wall with this one.

Code below produces "home" screen in image. With multiple rounded buttons created from a List with each including an icon and text.

What I need is to include a unique link to the onTap(){} call.

I'm assuming to add the screen name to the same List line with icon and text then use index inside the onTap... or something like that.

Help is welcomed and truly appreciated.

[image: Flutter Home Screen]

```
'''import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_firebase_auth/appbar/app_bar_title.dart';
import 'package:flutter_firebase_auth/drawer/drawer.dart';
import 'package:flutter_firebase_auth/drawer/end_drawer.dart';
import 'package:flutter_firebase_auth/logic/custom_colors.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  static List menuList = [
    _MenuItem(Icons.person, 'Mayor\'s Office', ),
    _MenuItem(Icons.people, 'Employees'),
    _MenuItem(Icons.chat, 'WeChat'),
    _MenuItem(Icons.cancel, 'OPEN'),
    _MenuItem(Icons.business, 'BizList'),
    _MenuItem(Icons.water_damage, 'utilities'),
    _MenuItem(Icons.map, 'Welaka Map'),
    _MenuItem(Icons.email, 'Contact Us'),
    _MenuItem(Icons.info_outline, 'About WelakaOne'),
    _MenuItem(Icons.add, 'About walsh+logic'),
  ];

  get index => null;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        backgroundColor: CustomColors.welakaoneBlack,
        title: AppBarTitle(),
        leading: Builder(
          builder: (context) {
            return IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
            );
          },
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Builder(
            builder: (context) {
              return IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer();
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      drawer: new MyDrawer(),
      endDrawer: new MyEndDrawer(),
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              CustomColors.welakaoneBlack,
              CustomColors.welakaoneBlueDark,
            ],
            begin: FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
            end: FractionalOffset(1.6, 1.0),
            stops: [0.3, 1.0],
            tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
          ),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: GridView.builder(
            itemCount: menuList.length,
            shrinkWrap: false,
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
              maxCrossAxisExtent: 200.0,
              mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
              crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
              childAspectRatio: 1.5,
            ),
            itemBuilder: (context, position) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {Navigator.pushNamed(context, _MenuItem(icon, title))},
                  child: Center(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Center(
                          child: Card(
                            color: CustomColors.welakaoneWhite,
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100.0),
                            ),
                            elevation: 8,
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                              child: Icon(
                                menuList[position].icon,
                                size: 50,
                                color: CustomColors.welakaoneBlueDark,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                          child: Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                            child: Text(
                              menuList[position].title,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Calibri',
                                fontSize: 16,
                                color: CustomColors.welakaoneWhite,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _MenuItem {
  final IconData icon;
  final String title;

  _MenuItem(this.icon, this.title);
}
 '''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track with `GestureDetector`. If you want to open to a new screen, you can use `Navigator.of(context).push` to push a new `MaterialPageRoute`. And since you are in a `GridView` builder function, you can use `menuList[position]` to get the current item. For example:

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    final title = menuList[position].title;
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text(title)),
        );
      }),
    );
  },
  child: ...
)
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly. I have navigated using drawers and  bottom menu bars but never from within a list. :)

Comment: I have "followup" question if you could answer. As every list item will be it's on screen how do I user MaterialPageRoute to push to the necessary screen? Where would I include the screen info in the list? Could be way off-base here but would think it necessary to place the screen with the icon and title info???

Comment: @WillWalsh Your list (grid) items are custom classes `_MenuItem`, you can add a field there.